# How change a Python file within a container

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have created a docker container with my flask app. and it works.

Now, I have seen that a particular app functionality has a bug, and I have modified the particular .py script to solve the problem.
How can I do to rebuild the docker image taking into account only the changes and push it with changes into the docker hub?
I'm looking for a solution that avoids recreating the image from the beginning and reinstalling the whole set of dependency from requirements.txt, but ju update a file.

Answer (score 0):

`docker build` will automatically build just as many layers as are necessary, and `docker push` will only push the required deltas.

This means you don't have to do anything special.

Comment: it doesn't work just using docker build. I have used docker compose-up at the beginning and docker created the image and container. Now with the new changes the container is updated while the image no. how can I do that?

Comment: @fflpdqqoeit that does not make sense. The container is a running image. It cannot be updated without the image being updated.